# MacVIM on Lion - Command-T opens new tab instead of finding files

Tags: osx-lion, macvim

I have installed MacVim and I'm trying to learn it. But one of the most useful commands for me, the Command-T plugin, doesn't work correctly on Lion. If I type COMMAND-T, it opens a new tab on my macvim! Just like it opens a new tab on safari, terminal, etc!

I googled around, but it seems that I'm the only one with this problem.

I tried \t, but nothing happened as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The default for Command-T window list is `<leader>t` not `<D>t` (the "D" modifier is the Apple Command key) and the default leader for vim is `\`. So `\t` should work.

First see if you can execute

```
:CommandT
```

If that doesn't work check if your vim has support for ruby by running:

```
:version
```

In the :version output be sure that you can see +ruby.

See Troubleshooting section of Command-T for more: http://amix.dk/blog/post/19501:

Comment: Thanks, that was it...I was confusing the name of the plugin (commandT) with the keys necessary to use it (I thought it was key command + T)!

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, I can't vote positively, but I clicked 'yes' on 'was this answer helpful to you?'